# gs:Unique performance over HTTP GET

Tags: geoserver, wps

I'm calling the following URL through a JavaScript application to obtain the unique neighborhood's names of my neighborhood layer.

`http://.../geoserver/wps?service=WPS&version=1.0.0&request=Execute&identifier=gs:Unique&DataInputs=attribute%3dnome;features%3d%40xlink%3ahref%3dhttp://.../geoserver/smurb/ows%3Fservice=WFS%26version=1.0.0%26request=GetFeature%26typeName=smurb:bairros_vigentes_3857%26propertyName%3dnome&RawDataOutput=result%3dformat%40mimetype%3dapplication%2Fjson`

The problem is that this call takes like 10 seconds to execute and the layer has like 90 geometries only. If I make the "same" call through GeoServer's WPS Request Builder, it executes almost instantaneously, but I suspect it doesn't do HTTP requests.

Anyway, there are any tips to improve it's performance? Other suggestion to obtain the same results are also accepted :)

Additional info:

- Geoserver 2.7.2
- Linux machine
- "..." in the URL means my GeoServer host

Comment: It sounds like you do not have a performance problem. What is the size of the response document?

Comment: The size is 1,2 kb

Comment: And the GeoServer is in my intranet